# How to adjust image size to fit in TabBar

Tags: image, resize, react-native, tabbar

I have an image 128 X 128, would like to re-use it in TabBar as icon.
But use 1x will be too big, is there any way to make the image fit in TabBar without import a smaller size image?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resizeMode('contain')?
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode

Comment: thanks i end up using "react native vector icons" module.